# Check if KeyPoint is NULL

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, keypoint

Is there a way in OpenCV to make a KeyPoint NULL or check if it is NULL?

```
KeyPoint kp;

kp = NULL;

If (kp != NULL) { //...
}
```

Here is the global idea of the method I need this for :

```
KeyPoint leastScoreKeyPoint;

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    leastScoreKeyPoint = NULL;
    for (int j=0; j<50;j++)
    {   
        //[...]
        if(calculatedScore<THRESHOLD){
            leastScoreKeyPoint = keypoints[j];
    }
    if (leastScoreKeyPoint != NULL)
        matches.push_back(leastScoreKeyPoint);
}
```

Or is there any workaround to this?
Thank you so much

Comment: What does it mean for a `KeyPoint` object to be NULL? Do you mean you want to make a `pointer` to a `KeyPoint` object and make THAT null?

Comment: What about `std::optional`?

Comment: What about std::shared_ptr<KeyPoint> ?

Comment: I updated my question with an example, please read it. thank you!

Comment: @MPops yes that's a good idea, but I don't know how (I honestly never liked pointers anyway)

Comment: You can set [one of its members](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html) to an illegal value. For example set the position to a location outside the image such as (-1,-1).